# answering user from dictionary django 1.9

Tags: django, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a beginner in python programming and I want to answer user's input from my dictionary.

This is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render


answer = {'Hi': 'Hello!',
          'How are you?': 'I am fine'}


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'answer/index.html', answer)


def detail(request):
    return render(request, 'answer/detail.html')
```

urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^answer$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

index.html

```
<form type="get" action="." style="margin: 0">
    <input  id="search_box" type="text" name="search_box"  placeholder="Search..." >
    <button id="search_submit" type="submit" >Submit</button>
    {% if question in answer.items %}
    <a href="{% url 'answer:result' %}"></a>
    {%  endif %}
</form>
```

When I put something from the server in submit box, I get the same page but '?search_box=Hi' this is added in the url. How can I respond? I have to add another template 'detail.html' but i don't know what should i put in it.

If you answer this question, write an explanation too, please.

Comment: So you're typing 'Hi' in the search box and expecting to get 'Hello' as the response ?

Comment: yes, Hi is the user's input and i want to respond with hello, it's like a mini-chat.

Answer (score -1):

You've not defined the form in forms.py or in the view, or how the view should deal with a POST request. So whilst the form submits the response, it has nowhere to go.  I would start here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Comment: this is not an answer, you say this at the comment section